# Is Pandas join memory efficient?

Tags: pandas

I am making calculations, creating a Pandas Series, and `join`ing it with a Dataframe, thousands of times.  The result in the end is a huge Dataframe, which is what I want.

Is this memory efficient, as opposed to some other way that I don't know about?  My concern is that when using `join`, it creates a new Dataframe in memory, with the old copies still hanging around.  Is that the case?  Are there any other concerns I need to watch out for?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is slower than first generate a dictionary then make it into a dataframe.

```
%%time
all_list = {}
for i in range(1000):
    all_list[i] = range(1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_list)
```

Wall time: 186 ms

```
import psutil
mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
mem
```

svmem(total=17056518144L, available=10201149440L, percent=40.2, used=6855368704L, free=10201149440L)

Then if I close and shut down the previous python notebook, and start a new one.

```
%%time
df = pd.DataFrame({1:range(1000)})
for i in range(2,1000):
    df = df.join(pd.DataFrame({i:range(1000)}))
```

Wall time: 19.5 s

```
import psutil
mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
mem
```

svmem(total=17056518144L, available=10402709504L, percent=39.0, used=6653808640L, free=10402709504L)

For memory it is smaller.

So I may conclude that

- Time cost: more,
- Memory cost: less.